# Splitting of string by spaces and outputting the columns into different arrays

Tags: c++, string, split, whitespace, delimiter

So i have this text file which basically has 2 columns of letters and numbers separated spaces. I want to split these 2 columns and place them in separate arrays.

I tried using the getLine method with space as the delimiter but I am only able to place them in the same array. I can do this with fileOpen.eof method but that causes too many problems in my program

```
while(getline(openFile, letters, ' ')){

    index++;     
    lettersArray[index] = letters;
}
```

I expect the output of lettersArray[index] to be a column of letters only.

Comment: Are you familiar with stream input operators? Something like `string S; openFile >> S;`?

Comment: @Beta yes i am but that method skips the first line of what i read from the getLine method for some reason.

Comment: Try using stream input, and *not* `getline`. They don't play well together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the *getline* function in the wrong way. Take a look at how it works here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

You are basically telling the getline function to use the space character to use as the delimiter. So it is processing the letters in the file in the odd numbered iterations of the while loop and the numbers in the file in the even numbered iterations of the while loop.

If you want to stick to using the *getline* function, here is a possible modification to make it work.

```
while(getline(openFile, letters, ' ')){

    index++;     
    lettersArray[index] = letters;
    getline(openFile, letters);
}
```

The call to the getline function on the last line of the while loop, gets rid of the remaining part of the current line.